# TypedError: Can not sign transactions for account andrius.testnet on network testnet, no matching key pair found in InMemorySigner

Tags: nearprotocol

When I try to call my create_account function on near-api-js library:

```
        await creatorAccount.functionCall({
            contractId: process.env.NEAR_NETWORK_ID || "",
            methodName: "create_account",
            args: {
                new_account_id: newAccount,
                new_public_key: publicKey,
            },
            gas: new BN("300000000000000"),
            attachedDeposit: new BN("10000000000000000000"),
        });
```

I end up getting an exception:

```
>  {"severity":"INFO","message":"KeyStore:  /var/folders/f4/qjf99cc92k5gm4n45c98h5480000gn/T"}
i  functions: Beginning execution of "api"
>  {"severity":"INFO","message":"Signer account:  /var/folders/f4/qjf99cc92k5gm4n45c98h5480000gn/T/andrius.testnet.json exists: true"}
>  {"severity":"ERROR","message":"Exception:  TypedError: Can not sign transactions for account andrius.testnet on network testnet, no matching key pair found in InMemorySigner(UnencryptedFileSystemKeyStore(/var/folders/f4/qjf99cc92k5gm4n45c98h5480000gn/T)).\n    at Account.signTransaction (/Users/bacis/Development/Catch/backend/functions/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:93:19)\n    at async /Users/bacis/Development/Catch/backend/functions/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:118:34\n    at async Object.exponentialBackoff [as default] (/Users/bacis/Development/Catch/backend/functions/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/exponential-backoff.js:7:24)\n    at async Account.signAndSendTransactionV2 (/Users/bacis/Development/Catch/backend/functions/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:117:24)\n    at async createAccount (/Users/bacis/Development/Catch/backend/functions/lib/lib/nearApi.js:61:9)\n    at async account (/Users/bacis/Development/Catch/backend/functions/lib/routes/account.js:13:9) {\n  type: 'KeyNotFound',\n  context: undefined\n}"}
>  /Users/bacis/Development/Catch/backend/functions/lib/routes/account.js:17
>          throw new Error(`Account creation error: ${ex}`);
```

I added some logs which confirm that the signer account does exist on that path:

`>  {"severity":"INFO","message":"Signer account:  /var/folders/f4/qjf99cc92k5gm4n45c98h5480000gn/T/andrius.testnet.json exists: true"}`

I haven't fully figured out what is the problem there, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what you do before the function call, but do you do the same as here? https://docs.near.org/docs/api/naj-cookbook#create-account

Comment: The only difference that I changed is signer key directory:
`import { tmpdir } from "os"; const keyStore = new keyStores.UnencryptedFileSystemKeyStore(tmpdir());`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by loading private key string from memory:

```
const keyStore = new keyStores.InMemoryKeyStore();
const keyPair = KeyPair.fromString(PRIVATE_KEY);
```